# No method matching error, but identifies matching method

Tags: julia

I'm getting the following error:

```
compressdictionary! ./Data/en1k: Error During Test at C:\...\nyblr_test.jl:96
  Test threw exception
  Expression: NodeModule.printdata(NodeModule.cleandata(data_nodes)) == data
  MethodError: no method matching cleandata(::Array{Union{Missing, Node},1})
  Closest candidates are:
    cleandata(!Matched::Array{Union{Missing, Node},1}) at C:\...\node.jl:69
```

What is this error trying to communicate to me?  It appears that the type defined in the cleandata method is the same type being requested.

Comment: Hard to say without a minimal example, but my guess is that you are defining your `Node` struct twice by replacing a module, leading to two different types with the same name.  Do you see any module redefined/replaced warnings?

Comment: This turned out to be it.  In the tests I was including both node.jl (while using NodeModule.Node) and nyblr.jl (which including node.jl and uses NodeModule.Node) which appears to be creating conflicting Node structs.

Is there a way to ensure Node is only included once and used once in the namespace?  Is it just a matter of ensuring that includes have proper scope of other includes?  I can't think of how, but this seems like it would cause problems as programs get more complicated in Julia.

Comment: Use `include` to organize how you define your code; use `using`/`import` to use it.  Tests should only use `using` or `import`.